# anchor tag css not working when convert to router-link in vue js

Tags: vue.js

```
 <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <!-- navigations -->
      <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/" >Home</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/vendor" >Vendor</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/supplier" >Supplier</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/aboutus" >About Us</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/shagunweddings" >Shagun Weddings</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/help" >Help</router-link>
      </ul>

    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <!-- navigations -->
      <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/" >Home</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/vendor" >Vendor</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/supplier" >Supplier</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/aboutus" >About Us</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/shagunweddings" >Shagun Weddings</router-link>
        <router-link tag="li" to="/help" >Help</router-link>
      </ul>
```

instead if looking as proper text it is looking as list.I am able to write css for core html file using naigation>ul>li>a{ padding: 18px 10px; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #252429; }but not when using router-link

Comment: Can you share your related HTML as well?

Comment: <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
              
                <router-link to="/" tag="li">Home</router-link>
              
              <li>
                <a href="#" title="#">A</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" title>A.1</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="list-grid-view.html" title>List a1.1.1</a>
                      </li>

Comment: post the code to your post please?

Comment: @SMAKSS...not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `router-link` like this:

```html
<router-link tag="li" to="/" >Home</router-link>
```

**When you put an attribute `tag` in your `router-link`** according to Vue [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link), **it will render as your defined `tag`**, so the above example will render like this:

```html
<li>home</li>
```

So for styling such a thing **since we are dealing with `<li>`** you should do this:

```css
.navigation > ul li {
  padding: 18px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #252429;
}
```

In the other hand **if you want it to render as `<a>` you should consider removing `tag="li"` from your `router-link`** so it should be something like this:

```html
<router-link to="/" >Home</router-link>

<!-- It will render like this: -->

<a href="/">Home</a>
```

So the styling of it will be what you tried before:

```css
.navigation > ul a {
  padding: 18px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #252429;
}
```

Comment: Now you got it, glad my answer could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set your router-link `tag` to `li`, your CSS needs to target `li`, not `a`.

```
.navigation li {
    /* your CSS */
}
```

You can also add classes to your router links, for more specific styling.